# How to find distance between a known point and midway along a hypotenuse?

Tags: math, geometry

Forgive my lack of math knowledge, its been a while since I've needed any of this. I'm attempting to programmatically find the distance between a point and the intersection directly below the point along the hypotenuse of a triangle.

[Here is my scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKcGx.jpg). All points have known x/y coordinates, I'm just trying to solve for the distance "A".   The intersection point is directly vertical.  I'll eventually have to do this horizontal as well, but I imagine if I can make it work vertical it shouldn't be too difficult to flip it horizontal.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing your 3 points are P1=(x1,y1), P2=(x2,y2), and P3=(x3,y3) where the line is defined by P1 and P2:

When you project P3 straight down vertically onto the line, the projection point has X coordinate of x3, and Y coordinate (you can derive this from the equation of the line):

```
y1 + (y2 - y1)*(x3 - x1)/(x2 - x1)
```

The (signed) distance between P3 and the projection point would then be:

```
y3 - y1 - (y2 - y1)*(x3 - x1)/(x2 - x1)
```

The sign of the value tells you on which side of the line P3 is. If you're not interested in that, just take the absolute value (typically `abs` function in math libraries)

Comment: Ooooh boy, that is so much simpler than what I was trying to do.  Thank you so much!